# Rails public_activity feed with polymorphic following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed, polymorphic-associations

I am using two gems in my app, public_activity and acts_as_follower.  I've got acts_as_follower set up fine where a user can follow another user as well as bands.

The problem is making a feed out of the activity from the objects you are following.  Using Public activity, I have a global feed using the recommended method:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
```

That works fine.  However I would like also to have a following feed, which would reqiure something along the lines of:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.all_following, owner_type: ????????)
```

Without specifying owner_type, a feed is created using only owner_id which is a problem because a user and a band can have the same id.  How might I specify the owner type in this case?

Answer (score 1):

For users:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.follows_by_type('User'), owner_type: 'User').order("created_at desc")
```

For bands:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.follows_by_type('Band'), owner_type: 'Band').order("created_at desc")
```

For a mixture:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where("(owner_id IN (?) AND owner_type = 'User') or (owner_id IN (?) AND owner_type = 'Band')", current_user.follows_by_type('User'), current_user.follows_by_type('Band')).order("created_at desc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Owen, here you use so called [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) try to figure out how they work. 
It is about just putting into the database not only ids, but the types of objects.